# Passage of time on a faster-than-light (FTL) vessel

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, arrow-of-time

Yes, this is already wild speculation. I'll retract this question if it isn't well received.

As I understand, within an event horizon, spacetime gets rotated so that the singularity is in the future, rather than in the distance. This is because every radial path is spacelike.

So could it be that on an FTL vessel, the destination seems to be in the future to those on board? Maybe the only way for the trip to *seem* instantaneous is to go lightlike?

Maybe it depends on whether or not you carry your arrow of time with you when you go superluminal? Maybe that's the core of the question.

Sorry if this question is too vague.

Comment: What is FTL, does it mean faster-than-light?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I assumed it was common knowledge. I will edit the question.

Comment: I disagree that FTL travel isn't part of mainstream physics, considering the work of Alcubierre and Van den Broeck, but I will remove the question anyway. Is there a Stack Exchange site where this question would be allowed?

Comment: Cross-posted on [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6086/passage-of-time-on-a-superluminal-vessel) and [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/18257/passage-of-time-on-a-superluminal-vessel).

Answer (score 0):

Superluminal worldlines are space-like: 'Time' on an FTL-spaceship would have to be measured with meter-sticks instead of clocks.

This is just one of the issues with tachyons (hypothetical superluminal 'particles'). Others are a failure to be properly localizable, processes with endpoints of the same intrinsic type on both sides (emission-emission, absorption-absorption) and the lack of a rest frame (in lieu thereof, there's a critical frame where instead of zero momentum, the tachyon has zero energy).

While something like tachyonic *interactions* might be possible if we extend the framework of special relativity (it has been argued that such interactions would not violate causality), they can't really be classified as particles. Macroscopic superluminal objects like rockets seem to be incompatible even with extended special relativity.